# JPQL : Adding days to date column

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a table which has the following columns :

```
APPLICATION
int id; -- PK
Date createdDate; -- date of creation
int actionReqdIn; -- no of days in which resolution is required.
```

I want to write a query which finds `APPLICATION` which are overdue i.e `createdDate + actionReqdIn > todays Date`

I am using JPA Predicate & JPQL to write my query. 
How to express this condition using predicate expressions?
Let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: AFAIK Standard JPQL doesn't support such operations on dates. But you can use native sql.

Comment: Any other option than native SQL? I am trying to avoid sql

Comment: So have you come up with some SQL that you think would do it ? because once you have then you can make use of JPQL using "FUNCTION" to call any native functions

Comment: @NeilStockton: Thanks for for your advice. I have created a SQL function and called it in JPQL